# Passing through variable to sub in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, parameter-passing

This is probably very basic, but I have tried so many things and the always give errors.

Basically what I'm trying to do is run a procedure every time a cell gets changed in Excel. So I'm using Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range).
All works well, but in this procedure, I'm calling another sub procedure several times.

I want to reuse the 'Target' value in this procedure, but for some reason, I can't find how to do it. I tried placing 'Public rTarget As Range' and do a 'rTarget = Target' at the beginning of the procedure. But the rTarget stays empty when I call the sub procedure.

How do I make this work?
I'm now adding Target as one of the variables to to subroutine, but that just looks stupid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MySub Target
End Sub

Sub MySub(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Your sub code goes here and can work with the Target Range from the Worksheet_Change Event
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing right now. But then I have to add 'Target' every time I call 'MySub'.
Isn't there a way of not having to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Passing Target as a variable is how you should do it. You want to keep your variables in the tightest scope possible and passing them as arguments is the tightest.

If you're passing the variable to a bunch of different procedures in the same module, it may make sense to have a module-level variable.  That looks like this

```
Private mrTarget As Range


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Set mrTarget = Target
    MySub

End Sub

Private Sub MySub()

    Debug.Print mrTarget.Address

End Sub
```

Based on your questions, it's just one sub that gets called repeatedly. In that case, I would stick with passing it as an argument.

Comment: I know I have to keep variables as local as possible. But the code I'm running is quite small, and it just makes it look neater without adding Target as an argument.
I was using the same code as you, but forgot to use 'Set' when copying Target to mrTarget...
Works like a charm now!
Thanks!