# Excel VBA - passing variables to a called sub/function: when, what and how

Tags: excel, subroutine, vba

I can't find in what cases I should pass something to a subroutine, and if so what I should pass and how. In a macro that I'm working on there is a loop that occurs several times, so I think it's better to put the loop in a sub-subroutine that I call in the main sub.
The loop in the main sub is the following:

```
For x = 2 To 7
        Bedrag = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rngUitgaaf, _
        rngInstrum, Instrum, rngKstPlaats, KstPlaats, rngWet, _
        Wet, rngRekening, Rekening, rngJaar, (Jaar + x - 2))
        If aantSub = 0 Then
          arrTabBegr(rijTabBegr, x) = arrTabBegr(rijTabBegr, x) + Bedrag
        Else
          arrTabBegr(tlrLezen + 3, x) = arrTabBegr(tlrLezen + 3, x) + Bedrag
        End If
      Next x
```

All variables, ranges and the array are declared, and it works fine in the main sub.

In the main sub I've replaced the code with

```
TelKasOp
```

The subsub is as follows:

```
Sub TelKasOp()
For x = 2 To 7
        Bedrag = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rngUitgaaf, _
        rngInstrum, Instrum, rngKstPlaats, KstPlaats, rngWet, _
        Wet, rngRekening, Rekening, rngJaar, (Jaar + x - 2))
        If aantSub = 0 Then
          arrTabBegr(rijTabBegr, x) = arrTabBegr(rijTabBegr, x) + Bedrag
        Else
          arrTabBegr(tlrLezen + 3, x) = arrTabBegr(tlrLezen + 3, x) + Bedrag
        End If
      Next x
End Sub
```

When I run the macro, I get a compiling error "Sub or Function not defined" in this line (the bold part):

arrTabBegr(rijTabBegr, x) = **arrTabBegr**(rijTabBegr, x) + Bedrag

Searching for a solution I think it may have something to do with passing ByRef or ByVal, or with (the lack of) declarations in the subsub, but I still don't know nor understand what to do.

Can anyone tell me why the error occurs en what I should do?
Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Step 1 in debugging: use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules (if you are not already doing so). Since we have no idea how or where (if anywhere) you have defined `arrTabBegr` and how you are trying to invoke unspecified subs, your question really can't be answered. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: We need to see the calling sub as well. If you are passing variables from the main to the sub routine then you need to pass those as arguments e.g. TelKasOp(ByVal arg1 As datatype)  .... Whether ByVal or ByRef again depends on the rest of your code and so we would need more context. Also, put Option Explicit at the top of your code to enforce variable declaration which will help with debugging. <== oops, what ^^John said.

Comment: When you running loop normally then it take `arrTabBegr()` as a array variable because you declared it as array but when you running the loop in `Sub TelKasOp()` then it is treated as a `Sub()` or `Function()` and sub `TelKasOp()` can't find it because it is not a sub.

Comment: Not the answer to you question, but best-practice advice...It only makes sense to extract code into its own `Sub` if that code is reusable as "stand alone" code (i.e. will it make sense to call that `Sub` from many other `Sub`s or `Function`s? If not, put it back in its original location. Each `Sub` should represent a single task.

Comment: Few lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217537/passing-through-variable-to-sub-in-vba?rq=1

https://www.homeandlearn.org/passing_values_to_a_sub.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904181/vba-how-to-use-a-variable-between-subs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference
 I suggest looking at some tutorials first.

Comment: Parameters are defined in the function/sub declaration. I.e. `Sub Test(parameter1 as string, optional parameter2 as string)` will ask for 1 mandatory string and 1 optional one. Functions work the same, but have a return value: `Function Test(parameter1 as String, optional parameter2 as Integer) as String` means: You must pass a string, you can pass an Int and the function returns a string.

Hence people are asking for your actual sub/function, since that will show what's going on over there. Lastly you might want to use English variable names instead of Dutch for readability.

Comment: As far as best practices go, I highly recommend the book "Code Complete" by Steve McConnell. My own programming improved dramatically after reading it. Since many of his examples use Visual Basic (at least in the first edition) it is fairly easy to apply his recommendations to VBA programming.

Comment: Thanks John Coleman, QHarr, harun24hr, Scott Marcus and Rik Sportel for your replies. I have some work to do...